# Using the output of a command to generate an ssh login

Tags: bash, ssh, pipe

I've got a script that I like a lot which generates a two-hopper ssh + port forwarded command.

`ssh -N -f -o 'ControlMaster Auto' -o 'ControlPath /tmp/gimme_access' -o 'ControlPersist 1m' -L 6473:33.22.0.0:22 -i /home/sink/.ssh/id_dsa -o 'UserKnownHostsFile /home/sink/.ssh/known_hosts' -p 6000 sink@33.22.177.16 ; ssh -p 6473 -l noc -i /home/my_boy/.ssh/id_rsa -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no'  127.0.0.1`

this gets me on a number of disparate gizmos and I could re-rewrite it to just log me on to those machines, but I prefer that the command just output the connection string.

Is there anything that I can pipe the command that generates the above string and leave me logged in.  I tried just piping to bash, but that logged me out right away.

Comment: Can't you just `eval` the string?

Comment: @nohillside "| eval" leaves me with ssh'ed in with a locked up console

Comment: `eval $string` :-)

Comment: Or probably rather `eval $(command-which-produces-string)`

Comment: @nohillside , that'll do ! sweet  - thanks. You want to make that an answer or is this too dumb of a question for a person who thinks they "know unix" to ask?

Comment: It's not a dumb question at all :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `eval` to run a command stored in a string (or based on the output of another program):

```
eval 'echo Hello World'
eval $(magic-ssh-commmand-generator)
```

From `man bash`:

```
eval [arg ...]
    The  args  are  read  and concatenated together into a single command. 
    This command is then read and executed by the shell, and its exit status
    is returned as the value of eval.  If there are no args, or only null 
    arguments, eval returns 0.
```